# Unable to SSH Login using kerberos

Tags: ssh, openssh, kerberos

## Setup

1. I have some basic KDC setup at kerberos.domain.intranet (This is in my own Intranet DNS)
2. I have another machine at xux.domain.intranet (This being the target machine to which SSH)
3. I setup the principal `host/xux.domain.intranet` in the KDC machine with kadmin.local and the command `ank -randkey host/xux.domain.intranet@DOMAIN.COM`
4. A then did extract a keytab of the principal with `ktadd -k /tmp/krb5.keytab host/xux.domain.intranet@DOMAIN.COM` and send it to `xux.domain.intranet` with `scp` at the path `/etc/krb5.keytab`
5. Then I did ensure myself of setting GSSAPI enabled in the sshd server and the ssh client of the client and different to the other two machine.
6. Then added another principal to the KDC which is named `testprin@DOMAIN.COM`
7. Ran `echo testprin > ~/.k5login` at the root account in the xux machine

`/etc/krbc.conf` at `xux.domain.intranet`

```
includedir  /etc/krb5.conf.d

[libdefaults]
    dns_canonicalize_hostname = false
    rdns = false
    default_realm = DOMAIN.INTRANET
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
    default_keytab_name = /etc/krb5.keytab

[realms]
        RAYMWM.MWM = {
                kdc = kerberos.DOMAIN.INTRANET
                admin_server = kerberos.DOMAIN.INTRANET
        }

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kadmind.log
    default = SYSLOG:NOTICE:DAEMON
```

`/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` at `xux.domain.intranet`

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

# This enables accepting locale enviroment variables LC_* LANG, see sshd_config(5).
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` at the client machine

```
#   $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.35 2020/07/17 03:43:42 dtucker Exp $

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no

# If you do not trust your remote host (or its administrator), you
# should not forward X11 connections to your local X11-display for
# security reasons: Someone stealing the authentification data on the
# remote side (the "spoofed" X-server by the remote sshd) can read your
# keystrokes as you type, just like any other X11 client could do.
# Set this to "no" here for global effect or in your own ~/.ssh/config
# file if you want to have the remote X11 authentification data to 
# expire after twenty minutes after remote login.
    ForwardX11Trusted yes

# This enables sending locale enviroment variables LC_* LANG, see ssh_config(5).
    SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
    SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
    SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL

#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.d/%k
```

## Error:

1. I ran `kinit -p testprin@DOMAIN.COM` in the client machine
2. Then tried to login to `xux.domain.intranet` using `ssh -vvv root@xux.domain.intranet` but it failed given that was asking for a password instead of entry in the target machine. And it gave the following error:

```
 OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l-fips  24 Aug 2021 SUSE release 150500.17.22.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/USERNAME/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "xux.domain.intranet" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xux.domain.intranet [192.168.0.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xux.domain.intranet:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xux.domain.intranet
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug1: Offering GSSAPI proposal: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-gex-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group14-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-gex-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group14-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,null
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:O3+90rcJZW4HEs/J49XF6rsxdY1ht1QlR+2vANOMN8M
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xux.domain.intranet
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.239
debug1: Host 'xux.domain.intranet' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:JjeQnEJb7nm13W46edAgER0NWlKc1Rk+n04MISoI0B4
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
```

Comment: The command should be `ssh -vvv -K root@xux.domain.intranet`. The `-K` is important. Secondly, the principle is `testprin@DOMAIN.COM`, that is not `root@xux.domain.intranet`, in that that user is is not in the kerberos system. Generally, the principal & base username should be the same, ie `testprinc`.

Comment: @Bib that is the reason why I added it to /root/.k5login.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the correct principal to `.k5login`. The full principal name is `testprin@DOMAIN.COM`, *not* just `testprin`.

(The latter *may* have worked if the principal realm actually matched your server's default realm, but in this case they are different – the principal is from the realm DOMAIN.COM while the server has DOMAIN.INTRANET as its default realm – therefore the client principal is "non-local" and no realm-stripping is done. But even if the realms were the same, I don't think that works in .k5login; I seem to remember that it always requires principal names with full realm.)